# XML transform to other XML

Tags: php, xml, xslt, transform

Everyday I need to translate formatting from XML(A) to XML(B) and save new XML on server. How is this best archived?

Ideas are:

- With PHP extract XML(A) and save to MySQL database. Print out new XML(B).
- With PHP load XML(A) and translate on to XML(B)

Can someone show an example on converting XML-tag into another Tag or Attribute?

Here is **XML (A)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventList><!--Movie description-->
   <listmovies>
      <Movie No="9111">
         <Name>filmtitle</Name>
         <Imagepath>imagepic1.jpg</Imagepath>
         <Synopsis>Cowboy og Indianer planlægger en surprise fødselsdagsfest for Hest, men ender ud i store
                problemer da de bestiller 50 mio. mursten til barbecuegrillen, i stedet for 50. Det bliver starten på en forunderlig rejse hvor trioen rejser til Jordens midte. Kilde: Angel Distribution
      </Synopsis>
      </Movie>
   </listmovies>
   <!--Event description-->
   <Event No="0003" MovieNo="9111">
      <Period>
         <Start Date="153677" Time="44400">2020-10-02T12:20:00+02:00</Start>
      </Period>
   </Event>
</EventList>
```

The result to achieve. **XML (B)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Movie description -->
<FluxAgenda>
   <Film id="9111"
         titre="filmtitle"
         resume="Cowboy og Indianer planlægger en surprise fødselsdagsfest for Hest, men ender ud i store problemer da de bestiller 50 mio. mursten til barbecuegrillen, i stedet for 50. Det bliver starten på en forunderlig rejse hvor trioen rejser til Jordens midte. Kilde: Angel Distribution"/>
   <!-- Event description -->
   <EvenementSimple id="0003" dateFin="153677">
      <Horaires>
         <Date date="2020-10-02" heure="12:20"/>
      </Horaires>
   </EvenementSimple>
   <Affiches>
      <Photo url="imagepic1.jpg" filmId="9111"/>
   </Affiches>
</FluxAgenda>
```

Comment: GREAT THANKS, THIS WORK. 

**one follow up question** 
 @Parfait

 What if I have multiple child Nodes inside a parent Node ???
`<Event No="0003" MovieNo="9111"><Period>.....</Period><Period>.....</Period><Period>.....</Period></Event>`

Comment: Once again, please respond under posted answer (not my comment) to @Sebastien's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64175800/1422451) not me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple XSLT transformation on your input XML to get the output you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="EventList">
    <FluxAgenda>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="listmovies/Movie"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Event"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="listmovies/Movie/Imagepath"/>
    </FluxAgenda>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Movie">
      <Film id="{@No}" titre="{Name}" resume="{Synopsis}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Event">
      <EvenementSimple id="{@No}" dateFin="{Period/Start/@Date}">
          <Horaires>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Period"/>
          </Horaires>
      </EvenementSimple>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Period">
        <Date date="{substring(Start,1,10)}" heure="{substring(Start,12,5)}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Imagepath">
      <Affiches>
          <Photo url="{.}" filmId="{../../Movie/@No}"/>
      </Affiches>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aixRuu/25

Comment: And PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with XSL module: https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php

Comment: Thanks I will look into this!

Comment: What if I have multiple child Nodes inside a parent Node ???
`<Event No="0003" MovieNo="9111"><Period>.....</Period><Period>.....</Period><Period>.....</Period></Event>`

Comment: Thank a lot, it helped :)